# Very simple jquery AJAX post issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I've been trying to find the problem for the last couple of hours, but no solution.
I'm having an issue with the following AJAX post request.

```
$("#about_button").click(function(e)
    {
        var about = $("#input_about").val();
        $.ajax
        ({
          type: 'POST',
          url: location.href,
          data: {
                    'about' : about,
                },
          success: function(message) 
          {

          },
          complete: function(message)
          {
              alert(about);
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Here is the html part of the code;

```
<textarea id="input_about" name="input_about"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="about_button" class="button" value="Update" />
```

And finally the PHP part at the beggining of the file;

```
<?php
require_once("headers.php");
if(isset($POST["about"]))
{
    $data= $POST["about"];
    $database->query("UPDATE hakkimizda set icerik='$data'");
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("dsdsfdsdfsf"); </script>';
}
?>
```

When I click the submit button, it goes into the complete function and alerts the data, but it looks like the page never receives the post message.
I don't if its related with my issue, but I'm using WAMP on localhost.

Comment: what about the rest of the html? the form tags? what is the action attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its `$_POST["about"]` not `$POST["about"]` also as it stands you are open to sql injections.

Comment: I can't believe I made a mistake like this and spent hours trying to figure out the problem:) it's working fine now. I'm using mysql_real_escape_string inside the real code just didn't want to post it here in order to keep the code simple.

Comment: It can happen, my advice is to enable error reporting and display errors, then it would of told you that $POST was undefined, tho as you were accessing it with ajax you might not have seen the error as your not outputting anything. Happy coding :)